# Equation (mathematical function) of ramp signal vs saw tooth signal

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, capacitor, current, resistors

I have a sawtooth current source whose peak value is 1A. 0A to 1A. with a frequency of 1kHz.

This current source is going to charge a 1F capacitor, so I was trying to find the equation for the current source so that I can calculate the voltage across the capacitor after 1s from time t=0s.

I understand that the equation of a ramp signal would be that of a straight line equation. In that case, is the ramp waveform similar to the saw tooth waveform?

Would there be any difference in the current equation of the capacitor between the two waveforms?

Why do we not include the frequency term while calculating the integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I was trying to find the equation for the current source so that I can
> calculate the voltage across the capacitor after 1s from time t=0s.*

If there's doubt, just use your good old trusted simulator to get your brain aligned to the right ballpark. Here's my attempt using micro-cap: -

[image]

A slightly closer look at the changing voltage waveform around 0.6 seconds: -

[image]

As you can see, the voltage rate of change is proportional to the current changing (as per the equation further down).

> *So, I was trying to find out the equation for the current source so
> that I can calculate the voltage across the capacitor after 1s from
> time t=0s*

It's not that easy to find an equation for the sawtooth waveform because it has sudden edges and discontinuities. Better to use a sim IMHO.

> *I understand that the equation of a ramp signal would be that of a
> straight line equation. In that case, the ramp waveform is similar to
> the saw tooth waveform right?*

No, a ramp is part of a sawtooth waveform but, they are not the same. A sawtooth has a ramp-up equation followed by an infinite slope ramp-down equation (aka a discontinuity).

> *So, would there be any difference in the current equation of the
> capacitor between the two waveforms?*

As always (and forever) the equation for a capacitor is this: -

$$I_C = C\dfrac{dV_C}{dt}$$

It's that same equation for all waveform types and amplitudes.

> *And the other question is, why do we not include the frequency term
> while calculating the integral ?*

Because we don't need to.

---

**Links to mathematical waveform definition for a sawtooth**

- [From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave)
- [From Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SawtoothWave.html)
- [From digital signals Harris](https://sites.google.com/site/2012digitalsignalsharris/--lab-2-fourier-transforms).

They concentrate on the Fourier version but, wiki does contain the formulas for a time-based waveform I believe.

**The capacitor voltage if just a 0.5 amps current source were applied: -**

[image]

I've changed the current source from a 0 to 1 amp sawtooth waveform at 1 kHz to just a constant current source of 0.5 amps. Can you see that there is very little difference in the capacitor voltage ramp. OK, if you are looking for minutia then it might be important.

Comment: @SamGibson maybe you can remind me of what I said. I probably said "some idiot" without specifically referring to anyone (not sure) then, when Miss Mulan said she did it, I was quite reasonable given her explanation and, that (possibly) unspecific idiot reference I made became cancelled by my subsequent words. So, I was not being specifically unkind; just as calling a book "an idiots guide" does not imply that everyone reading it is an idiot. I don't mind you deleting it but I take offence at you presuming I was being unkind at anyone specifically.

Comment: You said: "Some idiot is playing games". Calling anyone an idiot breaks the Code of Conduct - please [read](/help/conduct) where it says: "No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language." so IMHO an objection to my interpretation will be futile (but as always, you can contact the CMs to appeal). No subsequent words "cancel" anything. If you don't want to break the CoC then please don't write something that breaks it in the first place. We get complaints that this site can be "unwelcoming" & using words like "idiot" *anywhere* contribute to that atmosphere. So, again, please don't do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A ramp or a sawtooth are the same beasts, different names. Mathematically, both imply the use of \$kt\$ as the ramp (\$k\$ being some constant), and a modulo operation. Practically, there are two ramps, the falling edge counts, since otherwise it's a physical impossibility (well, it's more complicated because there are no sharp discontinuities, but very narrow transition regions, depending on the generator, parasitics, other non-idealities, and even the ramps, themselves, may not be entirely linear, e.g. flat derivative).

From the mathematical side, from \$0\$ to \$T\$ there is a ramp \$kt\$, which means the output will be \$kt^2/2\$. At the end of it the waveform drops to zero which acts as a reset. That means the output will remain with the last value, and the next ramp will yield the same \$kt^2/2\$ but with different initial conditions.

From the practical side (considering two ramps, discontinuous), the timescale is divided from \$0\$ to \$kT\$, and from \$kT\$ to \$T\$, so the output for the first section will be \$kt^2/2\$, the last value will remain there for the next section, whose integral will be a negative exponential proportional to \$(1-k)t^2/2\$, because there is a falling edge. Then the next rising will come with the same integral but with different initial conditions, so the output will be a series of rising exponential + reverse rising exponential, stitched at the ends.

If you were to implement this in LTspice as a behavioural source, you'll need something like this (I kept 1 Hz, instead of 1 kHz, for simplicity):

```
.param k = 0.8
if
  (
    time < k,
    time**2 / (2 * k),
    if
      (
        time < 1,
        time**2 / (2 * k) - (time - k)**2 / (2 * (1 - k) * k),
        time**2 / (2 * k) - (time - k)**2 / (2 * (1 - k) * k) + (time - 1)**2 / (2 * (k * (1 - k)))
      )
  )
```

(I hope I didn't mess up the parenthesis). Simulate this versus a triangular waveform with \$k\$ rise time and \$10-k\$ falling time (`PULSE 0 1 0 {k} {1-k} 0 1`) and you'll get this output:

[image: test]

The black trace is the current source with the capacitor and the blue trace is the behavioural source. Note that the last portion, from time \$1+k\$, is not matched. That's because in the code above I stopped at that time, otherwise I would have had to continue adding to the expression (you can spot the pattern). Note that in the derivations above I didn't use \$kT^2/2\$, which would be what you'd get for integrating \$\int_0^T{kt\text{d}t}\$. Instead I used \$t\$. That's because this is a continuous process, not the result of the averages. The result with \$T\$ would have given a fixed, average value; with \$t\$ you get the continuous time expression.

And, as you can see, if you make the falling edge converge to zero, you get the pure mathematical case. The effect will be that there will be no second, inverted exponential, which will be replaced by a "stitched" exponential, for the next segment of the sawtooth.

---

Edit: In case the integral part sounds fuzzy, this is what I mean: the "usual" integration is from \$0\$ to \$T\$, but that implies knowing, beforehand, what value will be at \$T\$, before the time reaches \$T\$. It also means that the results will not be continuous, rather they will have a fixed value, the average over that period, but this is not the case here:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{nT}^{n(T+k)}{t\text{d}t}&=\dfrac12(k+2T)k^2n^2 \tag{1} \\
\int_{n(T+k)}^{(n+1)T}{(1-k)t\text{d}t}&=\dfrac12(1-k)\left[(n+1)^2T^2-(T+k)^2n^2\right] \tag{2} \\
n&=0,1,2,...
\end{align}$$

(where \$n\$ represents the multiple of periods for the sawtooth). Everything after the equal for both (1) and (2) is static, nothing is time-dependent. So the integral needs to be changed from \$0\$ to \$t\$, because it's a real time waveform. But since the input is discontinuous (considering the above simplifications), there are points where the limits change to:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{nTt}^{n(T+k)t}{k\tau\text{d}\tau}&=(k+2T)k^2n^2\dfrac{t^2}{2} \tag{3} \\
\int_{n(T+k)t}^{(n+1)Tt}{(1-k)\tau\text{d}\tau}&=(1-k)\left[(n+1)^2T^2-(T+k)^2n^2\right]\dfrac{t^2}{2} \tag{4} \\
n&=0,1,2,...
\end{align}$$

Where I kept the \$t^2/2\$ part to be more evident that it's an integration of \$t\$.

Comment: I've added some small bits at the end, hopefully it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is very simple and it comes from the equation Andy showed you above by integrating all factors.

[image]

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you've fallen into the same trap I did when you down-voted me; you haven't specified what the waveform is of the current source. Yes you have \$I_C\$ in the formula but, you haven't told the OP what form it is in mathematically.

Comment: Yes but my answer is more technically correct because the OP wanted the voltage of the capacitor at any given time , not the current through the capacitor.

Comment: And, my waveforms show that voltage.